# The relation between using `std` and `no_std` attributes and including WASM

Tags: rust, blockchain, substrate, polkadot

I've just started to study substrate, and the [*Add a Pallet* tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/add-a-pallet/#import-the-nicks-pallet) already has me seriously confused:

> It is important to note that the Substrate runtime compiles to both a native Rust std binary and a WebAssembly (Wasm) binary. For more information about compiling `std` and `no_std` features, see XXX.

This is fine, I'm familiar with `std` and `no_std`. My impression is that you either have `std` enabled and compile to native Rust binary, or you don't and compile to WASM binary.

But then, when I check out the runtime's `lib.rs`, I find the following:

```rust
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]
// `construct_runtime!` does a lot of recursion and requires us to increase the limit to 256.
#![recursion_limit = "256"]

// Make the WASM binary available.
#[cfg(feature = "std")]
include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/wasm_binary.rs"));

// ...
```

This confuses me: Why is the WASM binary "made available" when `std` is enabled? I would have expected the opposite. And what exactly does "made available" mean in this context?

I dug a little deeper and found the following in an older version of the tutorial, which goes a little more into detail, causing even more grievous mental confusion:

> This is important to enable the Substrate runtime to compile to both native binaries (which support Rust `std`) and Wasm binaries (which do not: `no_std`).

(Again, this is fine, although I'm not sure what they mean by "support".) And then later, refering to the file whose first lines I've posted above:

> You can see that at the top of the file, we define that we will use `no_std` when we are not using the `std` feature. A few lines lower you can see #[cfg(feature = "std")] above the wasm_binary.rs import, which is a flag saying to only import the WASM binary when we have enabled the `std` feature.

What?!

So, if `std` is enabled, then we use the Rust `std` library *and* WASM? And when `std` is not enabled, then we *only* use `libcore`? This seems to completely contradict the earlier statements.

I am absolutely certain that all of this is the result of a seriously stupid mistake on my part, but I can't figure it out.

**Edit.** I've had an extremely enlightening conversation with Shawn Tabrizi on this topic: https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-docs/issues/531

Comment: Hi @mkl, Can you please support our Substrate StackExchange proposal: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126136

Answer (score 4):

The Substrate runtime code (including the pallets) has two compilation target: `std` for the native binary and `no_std` for the wasm binary. This is necessary because Substrate supports to run both the wasm runtime for upgradability, and the native binary for performance (or for testing easily).

When you compile a blockchain, it will call the custom build script (`build.rs` in your runtime crate) to build the wasm binary first, save it in the build dir, and then build the native binary with the wasm binary **embedded** in `wasm_binary.rs`. This answered your question about "made available".

Therefore the following code means, if it's in `std` mode, it will include the wasm file built in `no_std` mode, embedded in the `wasm_binary.rs` file.

```
#[cfg(feature = "std")]
include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/wasm_binary.rs"));
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This clears some things up, but I'm not 100% clear on this.

So the idea is that `build.rs` builds the Wasm binary of `lib.rs` with `std` not enabled. And if `std` is enabled, then the native binary is built with the Wasm binary embedded, correct?

But what if `std` is not enabled? Then `build.rs` is _still_ executed and builds the Wasm binary, right? But isn't then a `no_std` native binary built (which doesn't have the Wasm binary embedded), as well?

Comment: As far as I can tell, it’s extremely rare to build the runtime in no_std mode directly. The no_std build is usually only initiated from build.rs. However if you have to do so, it’s likely the runtime will be still built ti the wasm target, but then it won’t be embedded to the outer build because it’s not std.

Comment: Thank you! I believe that clears everything up.